# Select event listener doesn't work inside a forEach loop

Tags: javascript

Select event listener doesn't work inside a forEach loop.

This is for input styling when a user selected a value a input tag would be disable.

```
 var listOfSelect = document.querySelectorAll('select');
  var listOfInput = document.querySelectorAll('input');

  listOfSelect.forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('focus', function () {
      element.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    });
    element.addEventListener('blur', function () {
      element.style.backgroundColor = "#F0F0E7";
    });
    element.addEventListener('select', function () {
      console.log("OK")
    });
  });
```

I expect select event would work inside that loop.

Comment: and what is the error you are receiving ?

Comment: No error, but there's no alert when it's triggered.

Comment: You're after the `change` event, not the `select` event. Your other two event handlers do fire, however, it's hard to  see any visible change because of your colour choices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working with a select element, perhaps you intended to use the [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)? The [select event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/select_event) is for selecting text in a text input.

If you did mean to use the select event, then you probably want to iterate over the array of input elements rather than the array of select elements.

Answer (score -1):

Try using change event:

```js
var listOfSelect = document.querySelectorAll('select');
  var listOfInput = document.querySelectorAll('input');

  listOfSelect.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
   
     $(document).on('change', element, function()
    {
     element.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    });
    

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value=''>--select--</option>
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>3</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: There is no mention of jQuery in the question, so I wouldn't use it in the answer